# Why is the amount of bytes read different in each case?

Tags: rust, iterator

Snippet is trying to count the number of bytes read in the following `sample.txt`

**sample.txt**

```
one two three four five six
seven eight nine ten eleven twelve
thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen
%
```

**case 1:**

```rust
let file = File::open(fname)?;
let mut reader = BufReader::new(&file);
let mut buffer: Vec<u8> = vec![];
let num_bytes = reader.read_until(b'%', &mut buffer);
//println!("{}", String::from_utf8(buffer).unwrap());
println!("read_bytes: {}", num_bytes.unwrap());
```

> `read_bytes: 101`

**case 2:**

```rust
let file = File::open(fname)?;
let mut reader = BufReader::new(&file);
let mut num_bytes: u32 = 0;
for readline in reader.lines() {
    if let Ok(line) = readline {
        //println!("{}", line);
        let bytes = line.as_bytes();
        num_bytes += bytes.len() as u32;
        if bytes == b"%" {
            break;
        }
    }
}
println!("read_bytes: {}", num_bytes)
```

> `read_bytes: 98`

I can't seem to figure out why the two cases are outputting different results. Any help with appreciated thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs for [`BufRead.lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines):

> The iterator returned from this function will yield instances of `io::Result<String>`. Each string returned will ***not*** have a newline byte.

Your count is off by 3 because you have 3 lines in the data and newline characters are not being counted in the second example.